# Ocultar página de login para usuários logados

Tags: php

Fiz um código pra quando o usuário estiver logado, não consiga acessar a página de login, e possa ser redirecionado para a página do painel. Tanto a do admin quando a do usuário estão funcionando, mas quando alguém deslogado acessa a página de login,  aparece esses erros

> Notice: Undefined index: nivel in C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC9\data\localweb\site tcc\login.php on line 5
>
> Notice: Undefined index: nivel in C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC9\data\localweb\site tcc\login.php on line 9

E o código que usei para fazer esse redirecionamento foi esse

```
<?php
session_start();
include "php/conexao.php";

if($_SESSION['nivel'] == "admin"){ 

    header("Location:admin/index.php");

}elseif($_SESSION['nivel'] == "usuario"){

    header("Location:usuario/index.php");

}else{
    echo "loga ai po";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O erro existe porque para alguém que não está logado, a chave `nivel` não existe.
Diferente de JavaScript, que apenas retorna `undefined`, PHP lança um erro ao se tentar acessar uma chave inexistente.

Antes de verificar o que tem na chave, verifique se ela existe com `isset($_SESSION['nivel'])` ou `array_key_exists('nivel', $_SESSION)`, exemplo:

```
if( !isset($_SESSION['nivel']) ) { 
    /*não está logado*/

} elseif( $_SESSION['nivel'] == 'admin' ) {
    /*administrador*/

} else {
    /*usuario*/
}
```

Comment: Troquei o código que estava usando por este e agora está funcionando 100%, obrigada!